# How do i convert a functional component which uses default formik hooks to class component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a functional component which works well but I want to convert it to Class component for some reasons, but I notice there is no tutorial online that says how I'm to deal with default formik hooks and multiple props.

Here's the part of the code I'm finding hard to handle:

```
export default function BanksList({
  name,
  childToParentBC,
  bankResolve,
  ...otherProps
}) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [listofBanks, setListOfBanks] = useState([]);

  const { setFieldTouched, setFieldValue, errors, touched, values } =
    useFormikContext();
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't use any hook in a class component, they're exclusive.

However that doesn't mean you can't play tricks, ex. wrap a class component and then inside use the old function component.

```
  class ClassComponent {
    render() {
      return <FunctionComponent />
    }
  }
```

NOTE: class and function component are very different, people tends to compare them a lot. But IMHO they don't need to, because function component is only a function, therefore in order to persist anything it relies on the hooks which can't be used at all in class component.

Comment: So there is no way around it?

Comment: i add some hack to it. however it might not work for you. In short, there's no quick way if the underlying capability is implemented with hooks.

Comment: maybe you can tell us a bit why you would want to go back to class component, because most of people go the other way.

Comment: Actually the truth is I don't need to convert it to Class component (I hate class component), but someone sent me a code he used class component and now I need to pass the values to a Child component in another screen, or atleast send the values of the class component to be saved as it is part of a form.

Comment: I asked this question because I wanted to see how it will be done if it was possible